# Is there any known/standard encoding or cipher method that uses a 64-character alphabet from byte 30 (ASCII `0`) to byte 6F (ASCII `o`)?

Tags: classical-cipher, encoding

Is there any known/standard encoding or cipher method that uses a 64-character alphabet from byte 30 (ASCII `0`) to byte 6F (ASCII `o`)?

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a file format, and I have good idea of what some of the contents of the files should contain, but I'm not seeing any obvious patterns in the data that correspond to my expectations. The biggest peculiarity that I've been able to identify is the fact that the bytes are limited to this range (other than 4 `FF` bytes that begin every file). It's not Base64, Ascii85, or uuencoding, as far as I can tell.

If it helps, the byte distribution across the 152 files I have has `30` (ASCII `0`) as far and away the most common, followed by `45` (ASCII `E`) and `55` (ASCII `U`); `4B`, `6E`, and `4A` (ASCII `K`, `n`, and `J`) are least common. The file format dates back to circa 2000.

I'm wary to post actual examples of the data, as I don't know if the files contain any sensitive materials, but I can easily test hypotheses should they arise.

Comment: This better suits https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My guess is that it's a simple encoding of 6 bits (adding 0x30); I would have no idea how they map 8->6 bits (or even if they do - it's possible that the original data was 6 bits)

Comment: It sounds a bit like [uuencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) Unix-Unix encoding, but the range is different.